# Centralizar TextBoxFor com ícone em coluna

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, input

Estou tentando criar um formulário de login centralizado, porém com o código abaixo o input text fica alinhado à esquerda e o ícone à direita:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O tamanho do input está definido como 280px (default do bootstrap no arquivo Site.css) e isso eu não gostaria de alterar. Veja na imagem abaixo o resultado, gostaria de saber como juntar o input e o ícone, e que os dois ficassem ao centro da coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui implementar da seguinte forma:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div align="center">
                            <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 280px">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bocask8/5dm0jzqh/2/)